# If the row delimiter is %=$% (there is no \n char) and column delimiter is |#@| how do I find rows with different number of column delimiters in Unix?

Tags: awk

I have a delimited file called abc.txt. It has a header row with column names separated by comma (,). The row delimiter used is  %=$% (there is no new line character to denote a new line) for all the data rows and header row. The column delimiter for the data rows is |#@| . How can I find the rows that do not have 33 columns in data rows in Unix?

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to `%=$%` as the record separator in Awk (`RS` variable).  Use `,` as FS for the first record; while processing it, switch `FS` to `|#@|`.

Comment: However, note that POSIX says the behavior is unspecified if `RS` consists of more than one character. GNU Awk allows it to be a regular expression.

Comment: `gawk 'BEGIN { RS = "%=$%"; FS = "," }; NR == 1 { FS = "|#@|"; next } ; NF != 33`

Comment: ... or so you would think, but I can't seem to be able to get GNU Awk 4.1.4 to separate records on `RS = "%=$%"`.  I tried setting it with `-v` from the command line too.

Comment: How would I pass the file name and the END for the BEGIN statement?

Comment: BTW, I should have escaped the `|` in `FS`.

Comment: The file name goes after the program argument `awk 'code' file1 file2 ...`.

Comment: Don't just describe your input, [edit] your question to **show** us some concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: Regarding "there is no new line character to denote a new line" - a file without newlines is not a valid text file per POSIX so YMMV trying to process it using text processing tools (but in practice most versions of awk, sed, grep, etc. will probably be OK with it).

Answer (score 0):

I'm somehow not able to get GNU Awk 4.1.4 on Unbuntu 18 to work with `%=$%` as a record separator. The Awk macro in [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr) works.

Print the records that don't have 33 fields:

```
$ echo -n 'A,B,C,D%=$%FOO|#@|BAR%=$%X' | \
txr -e '(awk (:set rs #/\%=$\%/ fs ",")
             ((= nr 1) (set fs #/\|#@\|/) (next))
             ((/= nf 33) (prn)))'
FOO|#@|BAR
X
```

TXR Lisp regexes are `#/.../` and since `%` is an operator (non-greedy version of `*`), we have to escape it.

We can assign the field list `f` to itself with `(set f f)` to force the `rec` to be recaculated with `ofs`:

```
$ echo -n 'A,B,C,D%=$%FOO|#@|BAR%=$%X' | \
txr -e '(awk (:set rs #/\%=$\%/ fs ",")
             ((= nr 1) (set fs #/\|#@\|/) (next))
             ((/= nf 33) (set f f) (prn)))'
FOO BAR
X
```

The fields are `[f 0]`, `[f 1]`, and the whole records is `rec`: different from `$1`, `$2`, and `$0`. `(set f f)` is the shortest way to force a recalculation of `rec` from the fields in `f`, like `$1=$1` in Awk.

Back to debugging why I can't get it working the same way in GNU Awk ...

Got it:

```
$ echo -n 'A,B,C,D%=$%FOO|#@|BAR%=$%X' | gawk \
'BEGIN { RS="%=\\$%"; FS = "," }
 NR == 1 { FS = "\\|#@\\|" }
 NF != 33 { $1=$1; print }'
A B C D
FOO BAR
X
```

The `next` is missing in the `NR == 1` rule, so we are seeing the headers too.

Awk's `$` regex character needs to be escaped in `RS`, that's the problem. Now of course, I had tried that—but incorrectly, and confused myself:

```
# incorrect escaping of $
$ gawk -v RS='%=\$%' ''
gawk: warning: escape sequence `\$' treated as plain `$'
```

But what we are doing here is assigning a character string, which gets interpreted as a regex. Gawk is telling us that there is no `\$` escape in its string literal syntax, which is correct. What we need, though is to escape the dollar sign as a regex character. To get it into the Awk string, we have to escape it as `\\`, and that then escapes the `$` in the regex semantics.

Comment: As an alternative to escaping with backslash (which can get processed by shell and awk-strings on entry, thus requiring a superfluidity of backslash), quoting special characters in awk REs like `[$]` `[.]` `[*]` is more reliable.